# Adding slimscroll to reactJS

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to add Slimscroll to a ReactJS app and I see the scrollbar reflect in the browser dev tools but I am getting an error in the console and the UI is breaking. AS a sidenote, the app compiles successfully.

This is my App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import classnames from 'classnames';
import 'jquery-slimscroll/jquery.slimscroll.min';
import injectTapEventPlugin from 'react-tap-event-plugin';
import MuiThemeProvider from 'material-ui/styles/MuiThemeProvider';
import getMuiTheme from 'material-ui/styles/getMuiTheme';


class App extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        $(".scroll").slimscroll({
            height: '100%'
        });
    }
    render() {
       <MuiThemeProvider muiTheme={getMuiTheme(materialUITheme)}>
            <div id="app-inner">
                ....blah blah blah....
            </div>
       </MuiThemeProvider>
    };
}

module.exports = App;
```

Then in the `index.html` I added the `scroll` class to the `<body>`

I intend to use this on other places with an overflow like scrolling tables or lists, so I'd rather have the slimscroll function attached to a utility class I can re-use (i.e. scroll)

As you can see below, the slimscroll is passing to the DOM

[image]

But the UI breaks because ReactJS doesn't like the method I used in some way.

[image]

Lots of things not working (i.e. the menu, the page displays partially, etc)

How can I add slimscroll to ReactJS. I looked at react-scrollbar in npm but it requires to wrap the element in `<ScrollBar></ScrollBar>` and I can't do that to the body

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might not be a direct answer to your question. But it will solve your original problem. IMO It's not a good idea to use jQuery plugins with React. But you can use [react-scrollbar](https://github.com/malte-wessel/react-custom-scrollbars) as your main container without no visual difference from adding scrolls to the body. Here is a small example.

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { Scrollbars } from 'react-custom-scrollbars';

const App = () => (
  <Scrollbars style={{ height: "100vh" }}>
    <div style={{height:"2000px"}}/>
  </Scrollbars>
);

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Also, make sure your html and body have no margins.

```
html, body{
  margin: 0px;
}
```

Working Example: https://codesandbox.io/s/orLx4ZlL

Comment: I also am against using jquery with react. And I did inspect the react-scrollbar before but as your example suggested, I'd have to wrap my body  with the <Scrollbars> tags and my body is outside of a component and directly in the html. In fact, I don't think I've ever seen any react app with the body in a component

Comment: @LOTUSMS Not sure what you meant by that. In my example, `body` is still directly inside the `html` tags and all my react components are inside the `body`.

Comment: When I implement react-scrollbars, the body scrollbars persist and I get two sets of scrollbars. One from the body and another from the container that is wrapped inside the <Scrollbar>. Hiding the body overflow, makes all overflow stop inside it. Then the only way to make the scrollbars inside the body work is by giving it a fixed height. Meaning bye bye height 100%. It's too buggy. There has to be a simpler way

Comment: ALRIGHT!!! It took me a while, but it worked only by using the exact library that you used in your example. All of the other self-proclaimed "best scrollbars" are garbage. Thanks!